# Excel increase letter only every thrird row

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to get a lot of data from Sheet1 to Sheet2 but when I pull a command to the right it should only increase the "C" to a "D" every third row.
Because I have 3 commands to pull to the right and all should just increade by one not by 3.

A1 looks like this:

```
=WENN(Sheet1!C3>0;Sheet1!C$2;"")
```

B1 like this:

```
=WENN(Sheet1!C3>0;Sheet1!$A3;"")
```

C1 like this:

```
=WENN(Sheet1!C3>0;Sheet1!C3;"")
```

When I pull it to the right it they change like this:

```
=WENN(Sheet1!F3>0;Sheet1!F$2;"")
=WENN(Sheet1!F3>0;Sheet1!$A3;"")
=WENN(Sheet1!F3>0;Sheet1!F3;"")
```

But I want:

```
=WENN(Sheet1!D3>0;Sheet1!D$2;"")
=WENN(Sheet1!D3>0;Sheet1!$A3;"")
=WENN(Sheet1!D3>0;Sheet1!D3;"")
```

I hope you know what I mean.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useful `OFFSET` function, in order to control by how much you want to shift a cell to the right.

Since you want to shift 1 column (in Sheet1) every 3 columns (in Sheet2), you can use the following function:

```
=ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1
```

This will basically use the column number, divided it by 3 and round it. Then, we remove 1, because we don't want to shift the first 3 columns. If pull this to the right, you will get the following sequence: `0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3...`

Now you know by how much you need to shift the cell `C3`, you can use the `OFFSET` function to get the right data. Here are the formulas you should use in `Sheet2`:

**A1**

```
=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$C3,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1)>0,OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1),"")
```

**B1**

```
=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$C3,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1)>0,Sheet1!$A3,"")
```

**C1**

```
=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$C3,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1)>0,OFFSET(Sheet1!$C3,0,ROUNDUP(COLUMN()/3,0)-1),"")
```

**Expected result:**

[image]

---

You seem to be using Excel in German. Here are the translated formulas:

```
=WENN(BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Sheet1!$C3;0;AUFRUNDEN(SPALTE()/3;0)-1)>0;BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Sheet1!$C$2;0;AUFRUNDEN(SPALTE()/3;0)-1);"")
=WENN(BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Sheet1!$C3;0;AUFRUNDEN(SPALTE()/3;0)-1)>0;Sheet1!$A3;"")
=WENN(BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Sheet1!$C3;0;AUFRUNDEN(SPALTE()/3;0)-1)>0;BEREICH.VERSCHIEBEN(Sheet1!$C3;0;AUFRUNDEN(SPALTE()/3;0)-1);"")
```